# SQL Server insert statement which auto inserts foreign key

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

My application has two steps. First, a user enters relationship_name into ClientRelationships table and then the user enters data into ProspectInformation table. Note that the relationship_id column under ClientRelationships table is a foreign key (FK_Relationship) under ProspectInformation.

Can you please help me construct an insert statement where I can input all the ProspectInformation data and match the FK_Relationship to relationship_id using the relationship_name.

For example, relationship_name = Smith Restaurant Franchise et al and relationship_id = 1 (auto generated). While, prospect_name = Burger King (not null field) and prospect_id = 1001 (auto generated). I want FK_Relationship column in ProspectInformation table to match with relationship_id = 1. I want to use this insert statement in the SqlCommand of ADO.Net.

```
CREATE TABLE ClientRelationships
(
    relationship_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    relationship_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
); 

CREATE TABLE ProspectInformation
(
    prospect_id INT IDENTITY(1000,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    prospect_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    prospect_street VARCHAR(25),
    prospect_city VARCHAR(25),
    prospect_state CHAR(2),
    prospect_zipCode CHAR(5),
    FK_Relationship INT  
       FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ClientRelationships(relationship_id) 
               ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Here is my insert query which causes an error Msg 4104.

```
INSERT INTO ProspectInformation(prospect_name, FK_Relationship) 
VALUES ('Burger King', ClientRelationships.relationship_id) 

SELECT relationship_id, relationship_name 
FROM ClientRelationships 
WHERE relationship_name = 'Smith Restaurant Franchise et al';
```

Comment: please show what you have attempted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the insert statement and it works. See below

```
INSERT INTO ProspectInformation(prospect_name, FK_Relationship) VALUES ('Burger King', (SELECT ClientRelationships.relationship_id FROM ClientRelationships WHERE ClientRelationships.relationship_name = 'Smith Restaurant Franchise et al'));
```